# Error in loop / javascript euler# 5

Tags: javascript, loops, runtime-error

I tried solve the problem to find the first integer that is divisible by all the numbers from 1 to 20 inclusive, but my program went into an infinite loop. Please tell me where are my mistake and how to fix it, thanks in advance.

```
var number = 0;
var test = false;

while (test === false) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (number % i === 0) {
      continue;
    } else {
      break;
    }
    test = true;
  }
  number += 20;
}
console.log(number);
```

Comment: `number % i === 0` well, `number` is _always_ zero, therefore that check always passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (number % i === 0) {
      continue;
    } else {
      break;
    }
    test = true;
  }
```

So, say the number is 17, `i=1`, the `if` statement is true, so we hit continue,  which take us to the next iteration of the loop.

Then, `i=2`, the `if` statement is false, and we hit break, so we are out of the for loop.

Notice how you never hit the line that says `test = true`, so test is never true, and the loop continues, you just increment number by 20 each time.

Whenever we reach the end of the for loop or hit the break command, we reach the line `number += 20`, so number changes, but `test` does not.

So, here's my working solution

```js
    var number = 0;
    var test = false;
    
    while (test === false) {
      test = true
      number += 20;
      for (var i = 2; i <= 20; i++) {
        if (number % i !== 0) {
          test = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(number);
```

So, the logic behind this is once we are in the while loop, we assume that the number is what we are looking for, until the if statement evaluates to true and we are proven wrong. Then the while loop continues.

If we never run the code inside the if statement, then we have our answer.

Also, I incremented the number at the top of the while loop, otherwise you will have to subtract 20 from the final answer.

Comment: Firstly, the number can not be 17 because I had increased it from 0 to infinity in increments of 20 (20, 40, 60, etc.). Secondly, let the program work the way you say, but if it finds that number which divisible by all the numbers from 1 to 20 then goes through a cycle, and iteration for all 20 selected condition is `continue` and then the var test is set to `true`. But in my case its doesn happened.

Comment: First, i know it's can't be 17, I was using it to explain the logic behind your code. Second, if a number if divisible by 1 to 20, then we never go inside the if statement, since I set `test = true` at the start of the while loop, `test` remains `true` at the end, so the condition `test === false` is `false, and the while loop exits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I realized the error. And another question, let's say my version of the program cycle is reached the number that's divide all the numbers from 1 to 20, the loop 19 times selects the first condition `continue` and on the latest iteration(20) block of code `continue` skips the installation of variable `test` and begins again to update the variable `number` again.

Answer (score 1):

if (number % i === 0) always null because you have number = 0 and when you divide 0 by any number remainder is always 0. Once number incremented by 20 you will have remainder and it will go to else clause. But there you are breaking the for loop and it is exiting before it is setting the test to true. So, test is always false. Your while loop is infinite

Comment: no it does not, number changes. notice `number += 20`

Comment: According to [documentation(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue), *The continue statement terminates execution of the statements in the current iteration of the current or labeled loop, and continues execution of the loop with the next iteration.* So, you are only going to the next iteration in the `for` loop.

Comment: @vlaz, david is right it will reach to number += 20 when remainder of (number % i ) is not equal to 0. But it never updates test variable. So, no matter what happens test variable is always false

Answer (score 0):

You are using the **break** only to exit from **for loop** not the **while loop**. The **while** loop will always be **true**. That is the reason it is going to infinite loop